# In edge browser datalist drop down fonts are different, but in chrome it is similar to the website font

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I am using the custom font in our application, in chrome it applies every where, but in edge browser in data list drop down some other font is being applied. In select drop down it being applied. Issue in datalist drop down in edge browser

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Besides, you could also try to use F12 developer tools to check whether the resource is load success and whether it contain some error?